# Using modulus in a loop causes segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program to find the factors of a number.

My logic is: `if ((number % i) == 0)` then we have a factor. But if you the attached code, it will compile without error, but crash mid program.

If you replace the modulo operator with anything else, the program runs fine. So what am I doing wrong??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    vector<int> factors; 
    cout << "enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        if ((number % i) == 0)
        {
            factors.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    // display results
    cout << "factors are: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < factors.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i < (factors.size()-1)) cout << factors[i] << ", ";
        if (i == (factors.size()-1)) cout << factors[i];
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dividing by zero in the first loop iteration (when i is 0).

Let i run from 1.

Comment: Thank you. :P It's one of these issues you run into countless times over time. At some point you'll develop an eye for it.